# Login via Xpath VBScript

Tags: xpath, vbscript

Anyone has any example of entering username and password in gmail.com (or any other website to login) through VBScript using XPath?

```vb
Dim url, page, obj
url = "http://www.gmail.com" 
Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Run url 
Set page = Sys.Browser("*").Page("*") 
Set obj = page.FindChildByXPath("//*[@id='submit']", True) 
If Not obj Is Nothing Then  
    obj.Click 
Else  
    Log.Error "The element was not found." 
End If
```

Getting error on as object not found.

```vb
Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Run url
```

Also, how do I enter the username and password?

Comment: Are you trying to do this with plain VBScript? Because the code you posted looks like UFT to me.

Comment: I am trying to do this via VBScript but after a particular steps i am not able to proceed.

Comment: The code you posted is not valid VBScript. VBScript doesn't have builtin objects `Browser` or `Sys` (or `Log` for that matter).